# Image Crossfade with Javascript and CSS3 Transitions

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to get images in a slideshow to crossfade by using CSS3 transitions. I have the slideshow working and I know how to use transitions, but I don't know how to get the CSS and Javascript to work together to accomplish this. I am relatively new to Javascript so simplified answers are greatly appreciated.

Javascript:

```
var images = new Array()
images[0] = "img/1.jpg";
images[1] = "img/2.jpg";
images[2] = "img/3.jpg";
images[3] = "img/4.jpg";
images[4] = "img/5.jpg";
var timer = setInterval(checkImage, 3000);
var x=0;

function checkImage()
{
    if (x>4)
    {
        x=0;
        changeImage();
    }
    else
    {
        changeImage();
    }
}

function changeImage()
{
document.getElementById("slideimg").src=images[x]
x++;
}
```

HTML:

```
<img src="img/5.JPG" width="400" height="300" id="slideimg">
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you're asking for the whole thing including CSS, here's a working demo (requires CSS3 transition-capable browser such as Chrome, Safari or Firefox 4+): http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/cwP5Q/.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
<img id="slideimg0" class="slide showMe" src="http://photos.smugmug.com/photos/344287800_YL8Ha-S.jpg">
<img id="slideimg1" class="slide" src="http://photos.smugmug.com/photos/344287888_q22cB-S.jpg">
<img id="slideimg2" class="slide" src="http://photos.smugmug.com/photos/344284440_68L2K-S.jpg">
<img id="slideimg3" class="slide" src="http://photos.smugmug.com/photos/344286315_oyxRy-S.jpg">
<img id="slideimg4" class="slide" src="http://photos.smugmug.com/photos/344285236_hjizX-S.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {position: relative; font-size: 0;}
.slide {
    border: none; 
    opacity: 0; 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 2s linear;
    -moz-transition: opacity 2s linear;
    -o-transition: opacity 2s linear;
    transition: opacity 2s linear;
}
.showMe {opacity: 1;}
```

JS (runs when page is ready):

```
var timer = setInterval(nextImage, 4000);
var curImage = 0;
var numImages = 5;

function nextImage() {
    var e;
    // remove showMe class from current image
    e = document.getElementById("slideimg" + curImage);
    removeClass(e, "showMe");

    // compute next image
    curImage++;
    if (curImage > numImages - 1) {
        curImage = 0;
    }

    // add showMe class to next image
    e = document.getElementById("slideimg" + curImage);
    addClass(e, "showMe");
}

function addClass(elem, name) {
    var c = elem.className;
    if (c) c += " ";  // if not blank, add a space separator
    c += name;
    elem.className = c;
}

function removeClass(elem, name) {
    var c = elem.className;
    elem.className = c.replace(name, "").replace(/   /g, " ").replace(/^ | $/g, "");  // remove name and extra blanks
}
```

If you were going to do this for real, you should use a class library like jQuery or YUI which will make animations both easier and work in all browsers, not just CSS3 capable browsers.

Comment: I tried your alternate Javascript but it didn't work for me (the images didn't switch). Like I said, I'm new to Javascript so I wouldn't be surprised it was my fault. I don't currently have any CSS for this as I didn't know how to integrate it.

Comment: Since it sounds like you were asking for a whole working example including CSS, I've changed my answer to be that.

Answer (score 0):

edit:
I made a more extensible script than the one I previously posted
the s() function switches to the slide number, the p variable is the play/pause.
with that, you can easily make buttons to switch slides.
I made the images be inside links because you probably want to be able to click the pictures to go somewhere.

```
<style>
div{position:relative;width:900px;height:350px;overflow:hidden;margin:0 auto;border:solid 10px #fff;box-shadow:0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);background:#fff;margin-bottom:60px;}
div>a>img{opacity:0;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:900px;
-webkit-transition:opacity 1s linear;
-moz-transition:opacity 1s linear;
-ms-transition:opacity 1s linear;
-o-transition:opacity 1s linear;
transition:opacity 1s linear}
body{text-align:center}
</style>

<script>
var i=0,p=1,q=function(){return document.querySelectorAll("div>a>img")};

function s(e){
for(c=0;c<q().length;c++){q()[c].style.opacity="0";q()[e].style.opacity="1"}
}

setInterval(function(){
if(p){i=(i>q().length-2)?0:i+1;s(i)}
},5000);
</script>

<a href="javascript:p=1">play</a>
<a href="javascript:s(0);i=0;p=0">0</a>
<a href="javascript:s(1);i=1;p=0">1</a>
<a href="javascript:s(2);i=2;p=0">2</a>
<a href="javascript:s(3);i=3;p=0">3</a>
<a href="javascript:s(4);i=4;p=0">4</a>
<div>
<a><img src="Public/shot1.png" style="opacity:1"></a>
<a><img src="Public/shot2.png"></a>
<a><img src="Public/shot3.png"></a>
<a><img src="Public/shot4.png"></a>
<a><img src="Public/shot5.png"></a>
</div>​
```