# Add a fading effect to inside my JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, gallery, slideshow

I have a JavaScript function to display images in a slideshow by changing the source. I have tried to create smth to include a fadeIn effect but I think it was catastrophic..Here is my JavaScript function. I don't need a complete answer, just some tips helping me to achieve that. I'm a very beginner in JavaScript but I want to learn it well. If there is a way to do that without jQuery, it would be nice, or to include jQuery directly inside this function will be the best.

```
{       
    function nextImage() {

    if (currentImage < 5) {
        currentImage = currentImage + 1;
    } else {
        currentImage = 1;
    }

    document.getElementById('image').src = 'images/' + currentImage + '.jpg';

    }
}
```

Naturally, what the fadein will be adapt as a fadeout in the opposite function, but I think this example can help a newbie like me.

Comment: If you want fading you want to use jQuery...

Comment: It sounds like this is pretty close to what you're asking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6686650/image-crossfade-with-javascript-and-css3-transitions

Answer (score 0):

with jquery it would go something like this:

```
function nextImage() {

   if (currentImage < 5) {
       currentImage = currentImage + 1;
   } else {
       currentImage = 1;
   }
   $("#image").fadeOut('fast', function() {
       $("#image").attr('src','images/' + currentImage + '.jpg');
       $("#image").fadeIn('fast');
   });
}
```

Comment: This is awesome! Thank's a lot! I now understand how to compile this two scripts. Again, thank's a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a stupid question, though for whatever reason my own questions get downvoted, go figure!  (end rant)

You might consider if you are able to use CSS there are CSS3 fade transitions that you can try.

If you were to do it in Javascript I would probably use jQuery to do it because those functions are already there and all you have to do is use .show('slow') and .hide('slow') and that argument 'slow' will automatically do the animation for you.

http://api.jquery.com/show/

Otherwise if you want to write it from scratch, then you can probably look at the jQuery source code to see how the actual animation effect is done.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I know I can do it in CSS3 but to learn javascript and for a better fall-back I used jquery. But yeah you're right, CSS3 is really exciting for some things.

Answer (score 0):

You should JQuery as they have made it very easy to do the effects:

http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/fading/

Take a look at their examples and documentations

Here is an example:

Examples:
Example: Animates hidden divs to fade in one by one, completing each animation within 600 milliseconds.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    span { color:red; cursor:pointer; }
    div { margin:3px; width:80px; display:none;
      height:80px; float:left; }
      div#one { background:#f00; }
      div#two { background:#0f0; }
      div#three { background:#00f; }
    </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <span>Click here...</span>
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
<div id="three"></div>
<script>
  $(document.body).click(function () {
    $("div:hidden:first").fadeIn("slow");
  });
</script>
```

Some tips on how to start using JQuery:

```
var a = $(document); //  <-- set the hole document to variable a
var b = $("#myid"); // <-- set the element that has id="myid" to variable b
var c = $(".myclass"); // <-- set the element(s) that has class="myclass" to variable c
var d = $("img"); // <-- set the img element(s) to variable d
```

Use Chrome Web Inspector or Firebug to debug your JavaScript code